# I need some clarification on the correct use of a MAX3100 SPI UART chip

Tags: spi, uart, max3232, tmag5170

I have a system where I need to communicate with a TMAG5170 SPI-based hall-effect sensor chip over a distance of roughly 1.5 meters. Originally I planned to use the LTC6820 isolated SPI transceiver, but the chip is completely out of stock everywhere. My idea now is to use the MAX3100 to convert to UART, then convert to RS232 with an MAX3232 chip. On the microcontroller side, there will be another MAX3232 to convert back to TTL levels and read by the microcontroller as UART instead of converting back to SPI with another MAX3100. Does this make sense or am I doing something really dumb?

Here's a diagram of what I mean:

**[TMAG5170]** --{SPI}-> **[MAX3100]** --{UART}-> **[MAX3232]** ===={RS-232}====> **[MAX3232]** --{UART}-> **[uC]**

Comment: What about the [LTC4332](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4332.pdf)?

Comment: @VelVel Thanks for the suggestion, let me look into this chip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not make any sense.

Both chips are slaves so they both need to be connected to a master like MCU.

So the MAX3100 can't be a master to the sensor. It can just add an UART to an MCU for example.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me.  Do you have any suggestions to communicating with the SPI sensor over a long distance?

Comment: @user2218339 I don't know anything about your requirements so it is hard to suggest anything. If you make a new question about how to communicate with SPI over 1.5 meters and add the needed requirements/specs, someone might have an answer.

Comment: @user2218339 - Hi, Before asking a new question, please look at [this site search](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=spi+distance) as a starting point (or choose your own terms, if you prefer). If none of the previous Q&A about SPI at distance provide a solution for you, please explain why they weren't suitable when you ask your new question. That will help site members to avoid repeating suggestions you have already considered. Thanks.